# How can I at least estimate the optical power that an RGB LED radiates given the typical parameters?

Tags: power, led, rgb, optics

How can I at least estimate the optical power that an RGB LED radiates given the typical parameters - say luminous intensity in Candela or Luminous efficiency - from a data sheet? Assume this is a narrow-band LED and can be characterized by a single wavelength for each color, λ, to keep the solution from getting too complicated.

Comment: Yes you can. Divide the luminous flux with the luminous efficiency of the human eye. Link here: https://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org/Sample-Chapter.pdf#:~:text=The%20conversion%20between%20radiometric%20and%20photometric%20units%20is,referred%20to%20as%20the%20CIE%201931%20V%28%CE%BB%29%20function.

Comment: I think you mean luminous efficacy rather than luminous efficiency.  "Efficacy" is used because there are factors other than efficiency, namely that the human eye simply perceives some colors as brighter.  Seems like something that would be very hard to calculate and very easy to experimentally determine by comparing against a known wattage and luminous efficacy white LED.  That said, you can use the LED datasheets and a graph of human light perception ratios to determine light output for each color necessary to get the appearance of white at a given luminosity and calculate the power cost.

Comment: I've never bothered doing efficacy calculations for RGB LEDs though so I can't write an answer to walk you through it.  [Here's a link to a datasheet](https://cree-led.com/media/documents/XLampMCE.pdf) to get you started.  At first glance, the lumen numbers for the color dies seem low and unbalanced.  From experience, the LED doesn't require that extreme adjustment from rated current to be balanced, so I think this means you'll have to compare against a color perception chart to understand what the lumen numbers mean.

Comment: Perhaps that is why the Relative Spectral Power Distribution graph shows equal peaks for the colors instead of proportional to the lumen numbers.